# Iterate over dictionary using comprehension to convert all datetime values to MM/DD/YYYY string

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I have a dictionary where some fields are dates ( `datetime.datetime` type) and I need to use comprehension to convert those to MM/DD/YYYY strings in a new cloned dictionary.

I was getting started with

```
dict = .. # Existing dictionary

new_dict = {datetime.date.strftime(???, "%m/%d/%Y"): val for key, val in dict.items()}
```

But somewhere in place of `???` I need to insert a check for `isInstance(value, 'datetime.datetime')`. Any help appreciated.

Note: All keys are strings. Datetime Types can only occur among **values**. The new dict is otherwise a clone of the old one.

Example:

```
{'abc':'test','start_date':<Datetime>,'xyz':'test2'} --> 

{'abc':'test','start_date':11/05/2020,'xyz':'test2'}
```

Comment: If you have a dictionary of `datetime` objects it seems those objects are either going to be the keys or the values, but you didn't show the dict, so we don't really know what goes in `???`. My guess is either `key` or `val`. Also, what is supposed to happen if `isInstance(value, 'datetime.datetime').`is False?

Comment: All of these are values only. All keys are strings. If not a Date, we preserve the value from the old dict (it's a clone with the exception of Dates->MM/DD/YYYY string).

Comment: I think you have the keys and values backwards

Comment: The val is a datetime object, so your dict comprehension needs to be:

val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") and not datetime.date.strftime(???...)

Comment: Sidenote, better not to use `dict` as variable name, it will override the built-in `dict()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if isinstance(val, datetime) else val
```

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = {'abc': 'test', 'start_date': datetime(2020, 11, 5), 'xyz': 'test2'}
>>> {key: val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if isinstance(val, datetime) else val
...  for key, val in d.items()}
{'abc': 'test', 'start_date': '11/05/2020', 'xyz': 'test2'}
```

Comment: This works--thanks! Only change I had to make was `isinstance(val, datetime.datetime)`, it was complaining about just the `datetime`.

Comment: @geneb. Yup, you probably did `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import datetime`. Confusing names...

Answer (score 2):

[**Important**: Please, also upvote [wjandrea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67995475/206413)]

Is this the solution?

```
from datetime import datetime
dict = .. # Existing dictionary

new_dict = {
    key: val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if isinstance(val, datetime) else val
    for key, val
    in dict.items()
    }
```

Comment: I have to thank @wjandrea for the inspiration :-)

Answer (score 1):

Considering all val are datetime objects, your dict comprehension can be:

```
new_dict = {key: val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") for key, val in dict.items()}
```

If there are values that are not datetime objects, this will raise exceptions, though.

If you want to check with if and else statements, you can do like this:

```
new_dict = {key: val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") for key, val in dict.items() if isinstance(val, datetime) else val}
```

This will convert datetime to the format you have, but it will keep the val as it is if it is not an instance of datetime.

Comment: Actually, not all values are datetime objects, they could be completely different. Only the ones that are datetime should be converted. The rest should just be cloned. That's why I need some `isInstance(x, datetime.datetime)` check.

Comment: then you can use if statements, for example {key: val.strftime(format) for key, val in dict.items() if type(val) == type(datetime.now())} — or "if isInstance(val, datetime)

Comment: Won't that `if` statement simply omit the ones that are non-Datetime? I need to **keep** all the rest of them, and only convert the Datetime ones.

Comment: Yes, this example omits the value. But it is a conditional that you can tinker with. For example, if you want to keep the val as it is whenever it is not a datetime object, combine if with else statements: `{key: val.strftime(format) for key, val in dict.items() if type(val) == type(datetime.now()) else val}` — or else anything other expression you might want to put it there

Comment: An `else` there is invalid. When an `if` is at the end of a comprehension, it acts as a filter, but you can't have an `else` on a filter. You meant `{key: val.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if isinstance(val, datetime) else val for key, val in dict.items()}`

Comment: Yes, working. Only change I had to make was `isinstance(val, datetime.datetime)`, don't know why it didn't like just the `datetime`. Thanks again.

Comment: It depends on how you import it. The object is datetime.datetime. So if you import the datetime package, you will need to use datetime.datetime. But if you import as "from datetime import datetime", you are importing the class datetime from the datetime library. Confusing, but you get used to it the more you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
from datetime import datetime

dict = {datetime(2000, 1, 1): 'a', 'b': 'b'}

new_dict = {
    key.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if isinstance(key, datetime) else key: val
    for key, val in dict.items()
}

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'01/01/2000': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

Comment: Switch the logic to val if your datetime is in val. (Instead of keys, which is what I have above)

Comment: This type of technique is called dictionary comprehension with if-else condition.